# SQL: How to club multiple rows into one having same id

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following query

```
select r.role_id, 
r.role_name, 
p.permission_name 
from t_user_role ur, t_role r, t_role_permission rp, t_permission p 
where ur.role_id=r.role_id 
and ur.role_id=rp.role_id 
and rp.permission_id=p.permission_id
and ur.contact_id=505;
```

which gives me the follwing result

[image]

I want to club the rows having similar row id to get the result like below:

```
ROLE_ID                   ROLE_NAME               PERMISSION_NAME   
100                       ops_center               List Dashboard
106                       oc_public                RunETN Activity Detail | Run Test View | .... and so on
```

Please Help

Comment: Please specify which DBMS do you use! Without that, you won't get an answer to this question.... (Though you seem to use SQL Developer, so very likely you are using **Oracle**)

Comment: take a look at oracle LISTAGG() analytical function (assuming Oracle)

Comment: probably duplicate of this?

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Comment: Ppeterka: I am using oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your statement below, I am assuming you are using MySQL and have tried using `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

> *I have tried using Group Contact but I am not able to make a query*.

If you are using MySQL then you will apply [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) like this:

```
select r.role_id, 
  r.role_name, 
  group_concat(p.permission_name separator ' | ') permission_name
from t_user_role ur
inner join t_role r
  on ur.role_id=r.role_id 
inner join t_role_permission rp
  on ur.role_id=rp.role_id 
inner join t_permission p 
  on rp.permission_id=p.permission_id
where ur.contact_id=505
group by r.role_id, r.role_name;
```

*Note: I changed the query to use ANSI JOIN syntax instead of a comma separated list of tables*

In Oracle 11g, you can use [`LISTAGG()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm):

```
select r.role_id, 
  r.role_name, 
  LISTAGG(p.permission_name, ' | ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY r.role_id) permission_name
from t_user_role ur
inner join t_role r
  on ur.role_id=r.role_id 
inner join t_role_permission rp
  on ur.role_id=rp.role_id 
inner join t_permission p 
  on rp.permission_id=p.permission_id
where ur.contact_id=505
group by r.role_id, r.role_name;
```

Comment: Bluefeet: I am using oracle. Sorry I didnt knew Group_contact is in mysql and not in oracle

Comment: @bhuvan what version of oracle?  There is `LISTAGG` in 11g, see my edit.

Comment: Oh yes. I am using oracle 11g. Havent explore LISTAGG yet. Will do it soon

Comment: @bhuvan `LISTAGG` will be the best way (in my opinion) to do this, I updated my answer with a sample query and a link to the `LISTAGG` oracle doc

Comment: Thanks BlueFeet... LISTAGG was the first thing i did on Monday morning and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If I want to make a query for oracle 10g then what would be the changes? Reason for asking is that one of our client is using oracle 10g. So I need to write a query for oracle 10g so that it works with oracle 11g version as well

Comment: @bhuvan if you are not on 11g, then you should be able to use `wm_concat` or any of the methods described here -- http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php